# What is the error in each Java Statement?

Tags: java, class, object, methods

```
 //a.    
Rectangle   r   =   Rectangle(5,    10, 15, 20);

//b.
Rectangle   r;  
r.setSize(50,   100);   

//c.
Rectangle   r   =   null
```

Is that right that "new" operation is missing in a?
e.g.

```
Rectangle   r   = new Rectangle(5, 10, 15, 20);
```

Comment: Start [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/objectcreation.html).

Comment: If you want an answer, all can be valid, depending on the context you're using them (and with some bad naming conventions)

Comment: This question is needlessly vague, misses context and is also likely someone's homework assignment.

Comment: you never give any context. for all we know rectangle can be a method that someone is using although it looks like a class but lets not assume. Provide more context.

Comment: It's a question from one of my past papers. Just trying to learn objects, classes etc. maybe this forum is too advanced for this question. sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you are correct. By calling new you are creating a reference to an object, you are doing a similar operation when you declare a new String.

Comment: No. It's not a reference.

Comment: thank you and obviously for b. the object "r" has not been created before setting size to it. so pretty much same answer for that.

Comment: You're welcome, but I'm not helping you any more, as this does look like homework. But you should have an IDE available to test out the code, and that can tell you a lot about what is wrong with the code.

Comment: no it's a past paper i'm doing, some of the answers are a too easy for the marks they're worth so i thought i should double check. e.g. 3 marks for adding ";" to end of c. statement

Comment: Ok, you are right on C, and I believe you are right on B, but have not worked with Rectangles enough to be familiar with it.